# How to cut out directory as another partition?

Tags: linux, mount

Let's assume that we have two devices: sda1 (which has system installed on it /) and sda2 (which is clear, formatted partition). I have directory /data on sda1 which is used in real time by hundreds of processes (some write operations).
Is it possible to mount sda2 as /data folder (containing files) preserving [access to] all the files(?) and in the same time "cut out" /data folder from sda1 partition (and make it part of partition sda2)? I know that there is `bind` option in mount but it allows you only for duplication first directory to another.
Is it the only one solution to stop all processes, mount sda2 as i.e. /data2 or something else, move all files to sda2 and remount sda2 as /data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the only one way is to mount sda2 into /data2, move data from sda1 and remount sda2 as /data. Simultaneous mount of two partitions on one directory is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things, in case you find them helpful:

- Mount sda2 on /data while existing processes still work on the files they had open on sda1. When they close the files they will no longer see the files from sda1.
- Mount sda2 on /data in a new mount namespace, so that when you list files on /data you see the content from sda2, but the rest of the system still sees sda1. You can use `unshare` to create a new namespace.

What you can't do is cut a directory from one filesystem and paste it on another. The data has to be moved from one place on the disk to another, and that will take time.